# Can I filter multiple columns at the same time in Excel?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I haven't managed to find a good answer upon Googling this so here it goes:

I've got a large data set of people and within this there are two columns I want to filter: Location and Rating. I've worked out how to do one at a time (just the regular filter function), but I want to filter for both of these at once so that I have only people of X location and Y rating.

Is this possible?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: I've just added an answer, but if I've misunderstood your question please post a comment below it so that I can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something from your question, you've actually already worked out how to do this.

That is, if you first filter by one column the way you want, and then filter by the second column the way you want, you've effectively filtered both columns.

So, using your example, say you filter the location column so that only people in location X are showing. Then if you proceed to filter that list so that only those with rating Y are still showing, then the end result is you only have people of X location and Y rating listed.